# Create a Calendar event on the specific date at the specific time and then end on that date at another time

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I have a REALLY outside the box question!
I am creating a work flow for a school district.
Essentially .. Teacher fills out a Google Form I use Autocrat to automatically create a Google Doc with the information nicely laid out for the Principal.
I've scripted buttons at the top for each Administrator to Approve or Disapprove the request upon approval it automatically forwards the request to the next admin and signs the bottom etc. etc.

So the one I'm working on how is a Field Trip Request Form and I'm trying to get it to add the event to the Calendar and that is proving VERY difficult.
I have a table created on the form to more easily grab data from the Doc the Date is in the format of 7/2/2021 in its own cell as that is how the Google Form puts it in. The time is in another cell and is in the form of: 8:00:00 AM.

This table is on the Google Doc and is a 2x4 table that Looks something like this:

```
Field Trip Date: | 7/2/2021 

Destination Address: | Full Address Here 
 
Departure Time: | 8:00:00 AM 

Time of Departure from the Field Trip Location: | 9:00:00 AM
```

The Departure time is the event start time.
The Time of Departure from the location is the end time.

I am using the following script to pull that data in as a variable

```
var TableCal = location.getTables()[3];
var startDate = tableCal.getCell(0, 1);
var address = tableCal.getCell(1, 1);
var startTime = tableCal.getCell(2, 1);
var endTime = tableCal.getCell(3, 1);
```

The above works perfectly I'm using in other areas of the overall script.

**The script I have is here is the issue**:
No Errors but it doesn't show up on the calendar.
I have full permission to the calendar.

```
var event = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('lotsolettersandnumbers@group.calendar.google.com').createEvent(trip, 
  new Date(startTime),
  new Date(endTime),
  {location: address});
```

Noting that the startTime and endTime are both the times 8:00:00 AM and 9:00:00 AM. In the above I'm not using the startDate which is the date of the event.

I did try creating a new variable -

```
var comma = ', '; 
var start = startDate + comma + startTime; 
var end = startDate + comma + endTime;
```

Then I substituted the startTime for start and endTime for end.
This also did not work.
No errors the Script states it finished but nothing shows up on the calendar.

Any ideas???

What I need is to create a Calendar event on the specific date at the specific time and then end on that date at another time.

Comment: For the event creation function your using the time is ignored.  So this should have worked as long as startTime endTime are either Date() or strings that the constructor recognizes.  `var event = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('lotsolettersandnumbers@group.calendar.google.com').createEvent(trip,  new Date(startTime), new Date(endTime), {location: address});`  But since you didn't provide that information I can't help any more than that.

Comment: Maybe this will make more sense then ...

Comment: I don't see any changes

Comment: Just made them sorry

Comment: This is what it  says in the documentation `startDate Date the date when the event starts (only the day is used; the time is ignored)`  so if you just using time that probably won't work or it might be creating event in Jan 1, 1970 not sure.  It's best to follow the instructions of the documentation.

Comment: I tried with only the date in both and that did not work either.

Comment: The documentation only shows two things: 
1. How to pull in from Google Sheets (with Date and Time all in the same cell)
2. How to do it using Date('Month day, year, time)

I'm essentially trying to do something the documentation doesn't touch.

Comment: Date() is a datetime.  It's all in one object.

Comment: If Date() is datetime .. there has to be a way to change that or manipulate the code to make this work with a separate date and time.

Comment: No I don't think so.  Really date and time are the same thing

Answer (score 1):

Mine is just similar with yours but it works. I appended them just by using space (with no comma) although yours should work too.

#### Code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var startDate = "7/2/2021";
  var address = "Full Address Here";
  var startTime = "8:00:00 AM";
  var endTime = "9:00:00 AM";

  var start = startDate + " " + startTime;
  var end = startDate + " " + endTime;

  Logger.log(new Date(start));
  Logger.log(new Date(end));

  CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().createEvent('sample event',
    new Date(start),
    new Date(end),
    {location: address});
}
```

#### Output:

[image: Output]

#### Logs:

[image: logs]

Were you able to log your `start` and `end`? Try converting them to date and check their values. Include the values in your post.